# How to bind Array Texture 2D in Metal

Tags: ios, swift, metal

I am trying to use an array texture 2D in metal by following what I could dig about them from the internet. I was successfully able to initialise my texture array but now I am stuck with an error that shows up after binding the texture with `myEncoder.setFragmentTexture(myTextureArray, index: myIndex)`:

```
Failed assertion `Fragment Function(basicFragment): incorrect type of
texture (MTLTextureType2DArray) bound at texture binding at index 0
(expect MTLTextureType2D) for texture[0].
```

No idea what I am doing wrong here and unfortunately neither does Google. I guess I need to call a specific function to bind an array texture instead of the one used to bind ordinary textures (`setFragmentTexture`), or maybe I am mysteriously setting my texture type to be single 2D texture somewhere else and not allowing a texture array to be set? So my question is:

How to appropriately bind my texture array in Metal?

EDIT:

My fragment shader:

```
fragment float4 basicFragment(VertexOut vertexOut [[ stage_in ]],
                              texture2d<float> texture [[ texture(0) ]],
                              sampler sampler2D [[ sampler(0) ]])
{
    return texture.sample(sampler2D, vertexOut.texCoord, vertexOut.slice);
}
```

Comment: Show the fragment shader declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Metal Shading Language Specification](https://developer.apple.com/metal/Metal-Shading-Language-Specification.pdf), on page 26:

The following example uses access qualifiers with texture object arguments.

```
void foo (texture2d<float> imgA [[texture(0)]],
         texture2d<float, access::read> imgB [[texture(1)]],
         texture2d<float, access::write> imgC [[texture(2)]])
```

On the previous page, they show that instead of using `texture2d<type, access>`, you'd use `texture2d_array<type, access>` for a `2D` texture array. So I think it would be something like:

```
void basicFragment(texture2d_array<float> imgA [[texture(0)]],...
```

for example.